# Pandas DataFrame Transpose multi columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below.

```
a   x   10
b   x   11
c   x   15
a   y   16
b   y   17
c   y   19
a   z   20
b   z   21
c   z   23
```

and I want to transform it as below:

```
    x   y   z
a   10  16  20
b   11  17  21
c   15  19  23
```

Currently I am making the original DF into multiple Data Frames (each for "a", "b" and "c") and then transposing and merging back.

I am sure there would be an optimum solution. Hence looking for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
print (df)
   A  B   C
0  a  x  10
1  b  x  11
2  c  x  15
3  a  y  16
4  b  y  17
5  c  y  19
6  a  z  20
7  b  z  21
8  c  z  23
```

---

```
df = df.pivot(index='A', columns='B', values='C')
print (df)
B   x   y   z
A            
a  10  16  20
b  11  17  21
c  15  19  23
```

Or [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['A','B'])['C'].unstack()
print (df)
B   x   y   z
A            
a  10  16  20
b  11  17  21
c  15  19  23
```

If duplicates use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with aggregate function like `mean`, `sum`...:

```
print (df)
   A  B   C
0  a  x  10 <-same a,x different C = 10
1  a  x  13 <-same a,x different C = 13
2  b  x  11
3  c  x  15
4  a  y  16
5  b  y  17
6  c  y  19
7  a  z  20
8  b  z  21
9  c  z  23


df = df.pivot_table(index='A', columns='B', values='C', aggfunc='mean')
```

Or [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + `aggregate function` + [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].mean().unstack()
print (df)
B     x     y     z
A                  
a  11.5  16.0  20.0 <- (10 + 13) / 2 = 11.5
b  11.0  17.0  21.0
c  15.0  19.0  23.0
```